# AMD vs NVIDIA. How do they differentiate in terms of support of OpenCL?

Tags: amazon-ec2, opencl, nvidia, amd-gpu

I have an EC2 instance. It's specs are:

```
g2.2xlarge Instance.
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
NVIDIA GRID GPU (Kepler GK104) with
Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 bit.
```

I have two questions:

1. After installing the CUDA toolkit on this system, I have the following output when using `clinfo`:

   ```
   clinfo: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by clinfo)

   Platform Version:                 OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 8.0.46
   Platform Name:                    NVIDIA CUDA
   Platform Vendor:              NVIDIA Corporation

   Number of devices:                1
     Device Type:                    CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
     Name:                           GRID K520
     Vendor:                         NVIDIA Corporation
     Device OpenCL C version:        OpenCL C 1.2 
     Driver version:                 367.57
     Profile:                        FULL_PROFILE
     Version:                        OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
   //with other info too which I can paste if required.
   ```

   My question is: Is this a good practice? Will the GPU be used when coding with OpenCL?
2. Also what if I install the AMD APP SDK? Would that be able to use the Nvidia Graphic Card using OpenCL or will it use only the Intel CPU?

   I installed the AMD APP SDK on another ec2 instance with the same specs and found out the following from `clinfo`:

   ```
   Platform Version:                 OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)
   Platform Name:                    AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
   Platform Vendor:              Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.

   Number of devices:                1
     Device Type:                    CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
     Name:                           Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
     Vendor:                         GenuineIntel
     Device OpenCL C version:        OpenCL C 1.2 
     Driver version:                 1214.3 (sse2,avx)
     Profile:                        FULL_PROFILE
     Version:                        OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3)
   ```

   Does it mean that OpenCL will only be able to use the CPU. And the GPU (nVidia) will never be used? If this is the case, then should I turn back to the nVidia CUDA toolkit to make OpenCL use the GPU or is there some other way/better practise?

Out of the two, which one should I use? The CUDA tool kit? or the AMD APP SDK? My purpose is to run OpenCL cross-platform on all kinds of GPUs.

Comment: To put "NVIDIA" and "OpenCL support" in the same sentence is hilarious.

Comment: You mean to say I can't run OpenCL on Nvidia devices?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple OpenCL platforms installed (NVIDIA CUDA, AMD APP, Intel). The actual OpenCL implementation for GPUs is part of the display driver. The AMD APP also comes with an OpenCL driver for the CPU (AMD or Intel).

Apple also has their own OpenCL platform, they should support the CPU and GPU installed in the machine.

So, if you want to use the NVIDIA GPU on your server, you probably should use the NVIDIA CUDA platform, although some have claimed that it should be possible to use AMD APP as well. In theory any platform should work as long as you have the NVIDIA OpenCL runtime driver installed.

Comment: Do you have reference for the 2nd item in the list? I have been able to successfully use NVIDIA GPUs with AMD APP SDK. All those SDKs are the same, except for documentation, samples, libraries and tools. The actual platforms available are determined by the drivers installed in the system. You can use OpenCL without any SDK at all, using header files and ICD sources from the Khronos site.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to use OpenCL without any SDK at all? Do you know any proper tutorial you can refer me? Or some example? Also it would be nice if you could also provide some reference to the claim that Nvidia GPUs can be used with AMD APP SDK.... Because for me "clinfo" does not identify Nvidia GPU when I install the AMD APP SDK. But it does identify Nvidia GPU after I install the CUDA toolkit.

Comment: @void_ptr I have never tried using AMD APP with NVIDIA GPU. As you say, the actual implementation is in the display driver, so probably possible if you have the NVIDIA display driver installed. However, the user which posted this question apparently doesn't see the NVIDIA GPU after using AMD APP (see third printout). Also, the NVIDIA CUDA SDK have never listed the CPU as an OpenCL device on any of my machines. Will revise my answer.