# clGetDeviceIDs(-32). OpenCL error on ec2 Instance using Nvidia GRID GPU (Kepler GK104)

Tags: amazon-ec2, opencl, gpu, nvidia, platform

I have an EC2 instance. It's specs are:

```
g2.2xlarge Instance.
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
NVIDIA GRID GPU (Kepler GK104) with
Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 bit.
```

After following this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41103241/1900929 , I installed the CUDA toolkit 8.0 from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads. I also installed **"clinfo"**.

Then I ran `clinfo` to check the state of the OpenCL - IT WAS WORKING with the following output:

```
clinfo: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by clinfo)

Platform Version:                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 8.0.46
Platform Name:                   NVIDIA CUDA
Platform Vendor:                 NVIDIA Corporation

Number of devices:               1
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Name:                          GRID K520
  Vendor:                        NVIDIA Corporation
  Device OpenCL C version:       OpenCL C 1.2 
  Driver version:                367.57
  Profile:                       FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                       OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
//with other info too which I can paste if required.
```

By this time I though that since OpenCL is working, so my Program will also work. So I moved my program that uses OpenCL (c++ wrapper). But then it gave me the following error:

```
clGetDeviceIDs(-32)
```

This error refers to `CL_INVALID_PLATFORM` - ***IF AN INVALID PLATFORM WAS GIVEN***

NOW I don't know if it's the problem of the GPU - NVIDIA GRID GPU (Kepler GK104). Or if it is trying to take the CPU - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU as the first and/or only platform.

This is the code snippet that gives me the error:

```
try {
  // Create a "platforms" vector.
  std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
  // Get all the platforms
  cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
  // Create an array of platforms to save the platforms in.
  cl::Platform * platform = new cl::Platform[platforms.size()];

  // Create a "devices" vector.
  std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
  // Get all the "devices" for each "platform"
  for (int platformCounter = 0; platformCounter < platforms.size(); platformCounter++) {
      platform[platformCounter].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
  }
}
```

What could be the possible reasons for the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why create a  `cl::Platform * platform = new cl::Platform[platforms.size()];`  but not put any value into it and use it to get device?
You can directly use platforms in the loop.

```
for (int platformCounter = 0; platformCounter < platforms.size(); platformCounter++) {
      platforms[platformCounter].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
  }
```

Comment: with  platform[platformCounter] you are giving a uninitialized platform id to get the devices, that's the reason you get CL_INVALID_PLATFORM error.

Comment: So I should use platform[1].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices); ?

Comment: you have platforms there, why you need another platform?  use platforms[platformCounter].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices); is more than enough.

Comment: Side comment, if you are writing CPP code, don't make your like difficult using pointers. Additionally, when you don't need it at all, as given by @Tiget Hwang answer